# How to get the value of text box in query?

Tags: jquery

I have an tag like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="a" ></input>
```

and I tried:

`$("#test").val()` it returns `''`. Not `a`, why?

Comment: It is correct and returning 'a' see http://jsfiddle.net/p8hLdtz6/

Comment: using $("#test").val() works fine for me. what browsers and what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @atmd: Actually I'm writing test cases. The `value` should be populated by date picker. To mock that I have hard-coded. But no matter what, `.val()` should give me `value` right?

Comment: so what test framework are you using? whats your set up Re: fixtures? you need to give more information in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="a" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="a" ></input>
```

you have written it like a textarea..

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me,make sure you add the jquery link

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#showValue").click(function(){
var b =$("#test").val();
alert(b);
});
});
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zxsjefyb/1/